# C / GCC - What does 'at top level' refer to?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

This feels stupid to ask but I don't know the answer.

I've tried googling what I wrote as the question but nothing I answered my question. I also tried searching StackOverflow specifically as well.

When compiling code with `gcc –Wall`.

What does the 'At top level' refer to :

```
exam06.c: At top level:
```

Comment: Please add the full warning and the related code.

Comment: Most code is inside functions, and diagnostic messages tell you which function the error is in. If it's not in a function, it's at top level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the global scope, i.e. not in any other scope, such as a structure definition, function implementation, etc.

```
int globalInt = 0; // <--- at the "top level"

void someFunction() { // <--- at the "top level"
    int localInt = 0; // <--- in the function's scope
}
```